# Unreal Editor scale\view broken

Tags: graphics, game-engine, game-development, unreal-engine5

Problem: Objects can't be moved around using the widget and it seems like the engine isn't processing the scene properly

---

1. **Below shows that I can't move using object gizmo**
   [Demonstrating inability to move objects in editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OO3hd.gif)
2. **Below shows the improper graphics scaling**
   [Demonstrating improper view scaling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H79Vg.gif)
3. **Below shows another exampled of the weird issues**
   [Showing weird lighting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNIFV.jpg)

---

Tried:

- Deleting DerivedDataCache
- Rebuilding all levels
- Restarting PC / Editor

**EDIT: I turned off reflections and turned off Lumen and that fixed my issue for now**

Comment: Please do not use both UE5 and UE4 tags.

Comment: @Strom fixed, wasn't sure if it was version specific or general editor issue

Comment: I have voted to close, since the issue has been resolved, and is not going to be helpful to anyone later.